# Crawling only a certain file extension

Tags: 2013, search, 2007, crawling, crawl-rules

I am crawling a SharePoint 2007 site from SharePoint 2013 farm including a lot of folders and different file types. Only the PDF files are relevant to search. The crawl is very slow and I am interested in minimizing things in my index. Is it possible to set up at crawl rule that would crawl a certain file extension only?

Comment: Why not just set the File Types you want? In left navigation under Search Administration, Crawling, File Types.

Answer (score 0):

Create a crawl rule that only includes PDF files for the SharePoint 2007 URL.